# Trying to add object to IndexedDb: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found

Tags: javascript, service-worker, indexeddb

I am new to IndexedDb and I am trying to save an object using the [example seen here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/add#examples)

However, I get the following error when opening a transaction:

> Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

```
function saveIntoIndexedDb() {
    const DBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open("toDoList", 4);

    DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
        console.log("Database initialized.");

        // store the result of opening the database in the db variable.
        // This is used a lot below
        db = DBOpenRequest.result;

        // Run the addData() function to add the data to the database
        addData();
    };
}

function addData() {
    // Create a new object ready to insert into the IDB
    const newItem = [
        {
            taskTitle: "Walk dog",
            hours: 19,
            minutes: 30,
            day: 24,
            month: "December",
            year: 2013,
            notified: "no",
        },
    ];

    // open a read/write db transaction, ready for adding the data
    // ERROR OCCURS HERE!!! 
    const transaction = db.transaction(["toDoList"], "readwrite");

    // report on the success of the transaction completing, when everything is done
    transaction.oncomplete = (event) => {
        console.log("Transaction completed.");
    };

    transaction.onerror = (event) => {
        console.log("Transaction not opened due to error. Duplicate items not allowed.");
    };

    // create an object store on the transaction
    const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("toDoList");

    // Make a request to add our newItem object to the object store
    const objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(newItem[0]);

    objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
        // report the success of our request
        console.log("Request successful.");
    };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[JavaScript\]\[indexedDB\] NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507665/javascriptindexeddb-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-transaction-on-idbda)

Answer (score 0):

Object stores are used to store data in IndexedDB. In your code, you were trying to add data directly to a database without creating an object store. The error occurred because you only created a database, but didn't create any object store within it. However, I have made some changes to the code and created both a database and an object store. Then, I established the database connection and called the addData() method. As you can see in the screenshot, the data has been successfully added to the object store.

[image: IndexedDB]

```
var db;
function saveIntoIndexedDb() {
  // CREATE DATABASE
  const request = window.indexedDB.open("toDoListDatabase", 1);

  request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    var db2 = event.target.result;

    console.log("CREATE DATABASE");

    // CREATE OBJECTSTORE
    if (event.oldVersion < 1) {
      var objectStore = db2.createObjectStore("toDoList", {
        keyPath: "id",
        autoIncrement: true,
      });
      console.log("CREATE OBJECTSTORE");
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");
  };

  request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    console.log("SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE");
    db = event.target.result;
    addData();
  };
}


function addData() {
  // Create a new object ready to insert into the IDB
  const newItem = [
      {
          taskTitle: "Walk dog",
          hours: 19,
          minutes: 30,
          day: 24,
          month: "December",
          year: 2013,
          notified: "no",
      },
  ];

  // open a read/write db transaction, ready for adding the data
  // ERROR OCCURS HERE!!! 
  const transaction = db.transaction(["toDoList"], "readwrite");

  // report on the success of the transaction completing, when everything is done
  transaction.oncomplete = (event) => {
      console.log("Transaction completed.");
  };

  transaction.onerror = (event) => {
      console.log("Transaction not opened due to error. Duplicate items not allowed.");
  };

  // create an object store on the transaction
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("toDoList");

  // Make a request to add our newItem object to the object store
  const objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(newItem[0]);

  objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
      // report the success of our request
      console.log("Request successful.");
  };
}
```